# JavaFX css menu borders wrong color

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a JavaFX Application, with a MenuBar, with 3 Menus, with a few MenuItems each.

After changing the colors of the MenuBar/Menus/MenuItems, I have these brighter bars (below "Unterstützte Melder" and above "Daten laden")

[image: Current display]

I would like them to have the same color as the MenuItems Background color, i thought those were borders or shadows, but I did not manage to set them to 0 or remove them.

I use CSS to style all my components

CSS File:

```
.menu-item .label {
    -fx-font-size:14.0px;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.menu-item:focused {
     -fx-background-color: darkgray;
}

.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #8a8a8a;
}

#override:focused .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #ff8800;
}

#override .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #ff8800;
}

.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: #5c5c5c;
}

.button {
     -fx-background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.menu .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.menu-item {
     -fx-background-color: #5c5c5c;
    
}

.menu {
 -fx-background-color: #5c5c5c;
}

.menu:hover {
 -fx-background-color: darkgray;
}
```

Comment: Surely you want the background color of the context menu to be the same as the menu items to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have 1 `context-menu` on the scene at the same time:**

I succeeded to change the backgroung color of `Menu` node to red by adding this code to the style sheet:

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #ff0000;     
    -fx-border-color:  #ff0000;        
}
```

I suppose you are attaching your style sheet to the `.fxml` file, if no, you can do it by specifying the path in SceneBuilder:

[image]

**If you have 2 `context-menu` on the scene at the same time:**

Just specify **2 style sheets** and then attach them sepparately for different `MenuBar` nodes like on screenshot above. In each style sheet specify `.context-menu` class with desired properties. This way it won't override each other.

Comment: I have added my CSS file

Comment: @Dahlin I improved my answer, try it bro

Comment: the problem is that I have a context menu in the same scene, which gets the background  color #8a8a8a, which is exactly the color of those borders.
Which means, the container of the dropdown menu is a context menu?

Comment: @Dahlin, got it. Edited my answer, should help you if you have 2+ context-menus on the same scene.

Comment: yeah I simply didnt know that  it was a context menu as well